# How to access specific data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and I am wondering how would you access specific data. Ill give you an example, BTW I am using flutter.

Say I am creating data like this. I making a table of posts or I guess in firebase it'd be just a json array. In this json array I have 4 pieces of data state, city, post which as of right now just represents a simple message, and also timestamp.

So my question is how can I get a filtered version of my posts with a given city and state? Is there something special you can do in firebase? or would I have to do the filtering when I am building the list view?

I know FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('posts'); can access all of the posts.

```
var _firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('posts');
    _firebaseRef.push().set({
      "state": state,
      "city": city,
      "post": post,
      "timestamp": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question means you are adding data, not retrieving. If you want to retrieve data according to a specific city then do the following query:

```
var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('posts');
dbRef.orderByChild("city").equalTo("city_name").once();
```

`once()` returns a `Future` so you can use the `FutureBuilder` to get the data from the above query.

Comment: this is helpful but not quite what I am looking for. I want to grab all of the posts that contain a specific city and state. Then I want to create a list with them.

similar to this sql statement SELECT * FROM posts WHERE city = "Chicago" AND state = "illinois";

Comment: @Kyle What you are looking isn't available in firebase real-time database. You will need to build your own index to make it work in firebase. If you have an option I would suggest switching to firestore to store the posts. It has sql like functions (albiet with a few limitations)

Comment: @vvs thank you for the answer I will definitely look into firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Use Future Builder to fetch data to listview

create `getPost()` method first to return qn

```
Future getPosts() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("your_collecttion_name").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }
```

after that use, future builder to fetch data

```
return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getPosts(),
          builder: (_, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Loading..."),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Column(
                         children: <Widget>[
                             Text(
                               snapshot.data[index].data['your_data_field'] //name,age etc..
                                .toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                 fontSize: 20,
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),]
                          ),}
                        ),
                     });
```